# How to do bulk update of views?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

My database has about 30 views, most of which have a reference to another database on this server (call it `DB1`).

Now, without going into the reasons why, I need to update all those views to `DB2`, also on the local server.

I would hate to have to do this manually on each view.  Is there some SQL query I can run that will replace all occurrences of the string 'DB1' with 'DB2' in all my views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

navigate to the views folder, press F7 (Object Explorer Details) now from the right pane select all the views you want, right click-->script view as--> `DROP and CREATE TO` --> new query window. In there change DB1 to DB2 and voila

see image 
[image]

Comment: I was thinking about that too, maybe changing CREATE VIEW To ALTER VIEW would be a better choice  but then again a lot of people give dbo rights to users :-(

Answer (score 5):

You could query sys.sql_modules like this, which I'd use to generate a file via bcp (SSMS will truncate results) which can be run as another SQL script. This preserves permissions too.

I've used this technique before and it works.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE (REPLACE (sm.definition, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW'), 'DB1.', 'DB2.') + '
    GO'
FROM
    sys.sql_modules sm
    JOIN
    sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE
    sm.definition LIKE '%DB1.%' AND o.type = 'V'
```