# Is there a way to replace code and update a view using a tsql script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have about 20 views in a database that reference another database, let's call it database A. I need a way to update these views with a script to point to a different database, database B. Is there a way to replace the name of database A in the view with the name of database B using a single tsql script and keep the views intact? I can do a replace and output the views to the query window but I want to execute the ALTER statements that are generated and not have to run the output manually.

*Update* What I would like to do is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983927/6084613 but also have the output executed by the script. Is that possible?

Comment: SSMS: Right click the DB, Generate Scripts, pick the views, script to new window, search & replace, execute.

Comment: Thanks Alex K. That's the way I have done it for a long time but I need a faster solution. Also, with multiple databases, doing it that way is error-prone since I might update the wrong database (the default, for example) after running the replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put your query definition into a variable and then execute with sp_executeSQL.

BUT: I'd be cautious using the referenced script without more work.
For example, not all views have the exact text 'CREATE VIEW'.
If hand written , some might be ' CREATE VIEW' or 'CREATE   VIEW'  for example.
Also, 'DB1' might me written '[DB1]'.

So either add a lot more sophisticated logic, or validated everything by eye before exectuting.

```
   Declare @queryDef nvarchar(max)

   SELECT @queryDef = REPLACE (REPLACE (sm.definition, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW'), 'DB1.', 'DB2.') 
   FROM sys.sql_modules sm JOIN sys.objects o 
        ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
    WHERE
        sm.definition LIKE '%DB1.%' AND o.type = 'V'

    print @queryDef
    exec sp_executeSql @querydef
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks! The only issue I found is that it seems to only update one view at a time but I can save it as a function and execute it for all views returned from the search. I haven't yet found any issues with replacing the CREATE but good to know.

Answer (score 3):

I have created below SQL to do the same. this script will take 2 input 
1. Old DB Name
2. New DB Name
3. List of view you want to modify

```
declare @OldDb  varchar(250),  @newDB  varchar(250)
select @OldDb = '' , ---------->>> provide old db name
@newDB = '' ---------->>> provide new  db name

    create table #ViewList (Id int identity , ViewName varchar(250))
insert into #ViewList 
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS  where TABLE_NAME IN ( ) ---------->>> provide you view list 

create table #ViewDef(  ViewDef nvarchar(max) , ViewName varchar(250) ,Id int   )

declare @minId int , @maxid int , @sql nvarchar(max) ='' , @ViewName varchar(250)

select @minId = min(Id) , @maxid = max(id) from #ViewList

while @minId <= @maxid

begin 

select @ViewName = ViewName from #ViewList where id = @minId

set @sql = '    insert into #ViewDef (ViewDef)
exec sp_helptext '+ @ViewName +' 
update #ViewDef
set ViewName  = '''+ @ViewName +''', 
id = ' + cast(@minId as varchar(10)) +'
where id is null
update #ViewDef 
set ViewDef = replace(ViewDef , '''+ @OldDb+''','''+ @newDB +''')  
where id = ' + cast(@minId as varchar(10)) +'
update #ViewDef 
set ViewDef = replace(ViewDef , ''create'',''alter'')  
where id = ' + cast(@minId as varchar(10)) +'
'
exec sp_executesql  @sql 

SET @sql = ''

select @sql = @sql + ViewDef from #ViewDef  where id =   @minId   

exec sp_executesql  @sql
--print @sql

set @minId = @minId +1 

end
```

**Please test the script and save you old definition to avoid any loss in case of any bug in above scrip

Answer (score 0):

Using SimonB idea, I created a loop to do it automatically:

```
DECLARE @queryDef NVARCHAR(max)

WHILE EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM sys.sql_modules    sm 
                    JOIN    sys.objects  o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id 
                    WHERE   sm.definition LIKE '%TEXT_TO_REPLACE%' 
                    AND o.type = 'V'
            )
BEGIN
    
                                                                    -- TO ALTER THE VIEW AUTOMATICALLY                                          
    SET @queryDef = (   SELECT TOP 1 Replace (Replace (sm.definition, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW'), 
                                            'TEXT_TO_REPLACE', 
                                            'NEW_TEXT') 

                        FROM sys.sql_modules    sm 
                        JOIN    sys.objects  o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id

                        WHERE   sm.definition LIKE '%TEXT_TO_REPLACE%'
                        AND     o.type = 'V')
    
    EXEC sp_executeSql @queryDef

END
```